# Last item of istringstream repeats?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, istringstream

I'm having trouble with splitting a string with sstream. It appears when the loop of cout happens, the last item of data, an integer in my case, is repeated? Is my loop set up wrong??

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inputText("Jane Smith 18");

    istringstream iss(inputText);

    while (iss)
    {
        string first;
        string last;
        int age;


        iss >> first >> last >> age;
        cout << first << " " << last <<" "<< age << endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

See the picture - showing how the 'age' variable seems to be repeated. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance!

[Console-Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8m8N.png)

Comment: I just tried changing the 'int' variable to a 'string', and the 'age' variable went in without doubling. I'm guessing, but is 'sstream' not viewing placing the data into the 'int', as finishing the whole string? If so (or something similar), how would I get this to work, so that 'int' would be stored separately?

Comment: remove while loop, no need here

Comment: You need `while (iss >> first >> last >> age)`

Comment: @NeilKirk: Hmm. why does the last extraction into `age` not result in eof being set? I understand it for getline, but .... the stream would literally have attempted and failed [due to EOF] to extract another digit character by the time the loop restarts.

Comment: Guys that "duplicate" isn't even for the same programming language.

Comment: If you'd initialised your variables, you'd see that nothing is "repeated". And if you'd fired up your debugger, you'd have been able to count the number of times the loop runs, examined the stream state at each step, then used that information to determine _why_.

Comment: Ok my link was wrong.

Comment: @NathanOliver: What null terminator??

Comment: Except: http://ideone.com/jSrIh0

Comment: @NeilKirk I was incorrect.  the real reason is `operator bool` on the stream will return `true` if only the EOF flag is true.  see the table at the bottom of: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - sorry, I'm still learning, but does this mean that 'iss' within the 'while' is basically just checking 'eof'? So continue until 'eof'? I thought it meant do until all items have been split - but that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Robert_C: Neither the while loop nor the booleanisation of the expression `iss` have any idea that your program is intended to "split all items". It checks the "state" of the stream, which turns bad when an extraction fails (due to e.g. a `'a'` in the wrong place in the buffer which cannot be extracted into an `int`) or when an extraction has been attempted past end-of-file (the "past" here being important).