# Use conditional to determine elements within a string

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

This is an extension on my last question ([Last item of istringstream repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33325548/last-item-of-istringstream-repeats)).

I need to determine whether a string contains two pieces of data, or three. I'm using an 'if' conditional to determine this, however I'm not getting the results I was hoping - I realise I'm missing something.

The first part of the **if**, checks if there is only a first name, and an age present - if this doesn't work, it should then try the next part (my **else if**), which allows for three - where there is a first, last, and age. This isn't working when I try a first, last, and age (though does if I've only got first and age), and I'm getting the results from my bottom **else** statement - which means the other two failed. Could this be explained to me, and possibly help me fix my code so it does what I'm after? I really appreciate your help!

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string first;
    string last;
    string fullName;
    int age;
    //string number;

    string inputText("Jane Smith 18");

    istringstream iss(inputText);


    if (iss >> first >> age)
    {
        cout << "Only first and age detected.";
    }
    else if (iss >> first >> last >> age)
    {


        while (iss >> first >> last >> age)
        {
            iss >> first >> last >> age;
            fullName = first + " " + last;

            cout << fullName << " " << age << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed";
    }


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it you think `iss >> ` does? Every time you do that it reads some data from the stream. Once the data's been read, it's not in the stream any more and can't be read again.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for the reply - I'm still learning, but telling me that was incredibly helpful. I didn't realise that it only used it once. Should I pop it into a loop? Though, what would that look like? 
Otherwise, perhaps I could count the number of items in the string - kind of like this (http://ideone.com/tJdjR)? But this won't work for me, as studio is saying there is no suitable conversion to 'bool'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The conditional in the following line

```
if (iss >> first >> age)
```

evaluates to `false` since `age` couldn't be extracted from the string.

The conditional in the following line

```
else if (iss >> first >> last >> age)
```

doesn't extract any input from `iss` since `iss` already in an error state. The conditional evaluates to `false`.

That means, code block under the statement

```
else
```

is executed.

**One Solution**

```
// Extract the first name
if ( !(iss >> first) )
{
   // If we fail to extract the first name, the string is not right.
   // Deal with error.
   cout << "Failed" << endl;
   exit(0); // ???
}

// Try to extract age.
if ( iss >> age )
{
   // Age was successfully extracted.
   cout << "Only first and age detected.";
}
else
{
   // Clear the error state of the stream.
   iss.clear();

   // Now try to extract the last name and age.
   if ( iss >> last >> age )
   {
      fullName = first + " " + last;
      cout << fullName << " " << age << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      // Deal with error.
      cout << "Failed" << endl;
      exit(0); // ???
   }
}
```